# Highcharts x axis label

Tags: label, highcharts

Using highstock charts(V 5.0.6) facing a strange problem with x axis label. Initially labels are like[image]

After drill-down labels gets distorted change to this

[image]

And when user scrolls after drill-down labels are again back to initial stage (rotated at 45 degrees). Need help !!!

Comment: Can you paste code here or recreate the issue on jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/5vsL31d4/